i facing problem with multer package in express js
to upload files i configured multer package.i want server only accept image file.when server detect file other than image(except image file) then server will send error with response.the problem is when i upload files (rar file,java file,text file,zip file,pdf,pyhon file etc) then server response accurately but, when i upload files like auido,video,.exe file then server is not responding it means response is pending and there is no error on server-side too,i this situation i don't know what should i do. i'm new to MERN stack development can anyone help me please
this is app.js on server side
const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

// Multer storage configuration
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'uploads/');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname));
  }
});

// Multer upload configuration
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
    if (!file.originalname.match(/\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$/)) {
      // Error if file is not an image
      return cb(new Error('Only images are allowed!'));
    }
    cb(null, true);
  }
});

// Route for uploading images
app.post('/upload', upload.single('image'), (req, res) => {
  if (!req.file) {
    // If no file was uploaded
    return res.status(400).send('Please upload an image file.');
  }
  res.send('Image uploaded successfully!');
});

// Error handler middleware
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send('Something broke!');
});

// Start the server
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});

index.html file

<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Upload Image</h2>
  <form id="image-form">
    <input type="file" id="image-file" name="image" accept="image/*" required>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form>
  <div id="message"></div>

<script>
document.getElementById('image-form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  
  const formData = new FormData();
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('image-file');
  const file = fileInput.files[0];
  
  formData.append('image', file);
  
  fetch('/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: formData
  })
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Image uploaded successfully!';
    } else {
      throw new Error('Image upload failed.');
    }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + error.message;
  });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>


when i uploading image
when i uploading file like txt,java,py,pdf etc
when i uploading file like video,audio etc

It can be due to files too big. Where are you hosting the project? Also, a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you
